How to bind a property from a parent
My problem is that I don't know how to bind the property of the element that the HierarchicalDataTemplate acts on. My element class has a color, and a list of points to draw and use the color from the first class. In my case, trying “{Binding Fill}” nothing works and nothing is drawn in Canvas (I think it is colorless). But by changing this property to “Red” for example, my chart becomes visible.
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type shape:CurveLine}" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
    <Polyline Points="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource ConverterPointsCollection}}" 
              Stroke="{Binding Fill}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

And here's the model class:
public class CurveLine : Shape
{
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; } = new List<Point>();
    public CurveLine(int x, int y) : base(x, y) { }
}


System.Windows.Shapes.Shape abstract class does not contain a constructor that takes two int arguments. What is your Shape class?

@emoacht I'm sorry, I forgot to explain. In MVVM, in my opinion, the use of System.Windows classes is not desirable, so I try to mention them less in the code, so I created my own Shape class, which stores the position, size and color of the shape

Could you include your Shape class in question? Does it contain a System.Windows.Media.Color property instead of System.Windows.Media.Brush?
